# Match Legend Order with Bar Order in Stacked Bar Chart with Pos and Neg values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code that produces a stacked bar chart.

I would like to preserve the order of the bars (from top to bottom: Expansion, New, Contraction, Churned), while also having the legend order be in the same way.

When I change the levels of the `type` factor, it reorders the legend correctly, but then changes the order in the plot. How can I get the two to match?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249529/order-in-stacked-bar-with-both-pos-and-neg-values-ggplot2), but the accepted answer's plot and legend don't match up in the same order.

Here is some simple code to demonstrate:

```
library(tidyverse)


df1 <- data.frame(
  date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-04-01'), 'month'), 4),
  type = c(rep('New', 4), rep('Expansion', 4), rep('Contraction', 4), rep('Churned', 4)),
  value = c(100, 75, 200, 150, 50, 40, 75, 90, -10, -40, -25, -15, -5, -10, -10, -20)
)

df1$type <- factor(df1$type, levels = c('Expansion', 'New', 'Churned', 'Contraction'))

ggplot(df1,
       aes(x = date,
           y = value,
           fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: Sample plot]

Comment: Try with `scale_fill_discrete(limits = c('Expansion', 'New', 'Contraction','Churned'))`.

Comment: Thanks! This did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to set the order of the fill with `scale_fill_discrete`:

```
ggplot(df1,
       aes(x = date,
           y = value,
           fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c('Expansion', 'New', 'Contraction', 'Churned'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This did it